# terminal vim window gets distorted after switching tab

Tags: terminal, vim, display

My vim always gets distorted after I switch between tabs in the terminal.

The correct display[image]

The distorted display

[image]

This always happen when I switch back to the vim tab and gets back to normal after I press a move like j or k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you, by any chance, have different font size in your other tabs?

When switching between tabs of different font size in a maximized/fullscreen `gnome-terminal` (or `mate-terminal`), weird sizing issues occur. The terminal emulator wants to resize itself (to keep the same number of character cells as you can see with unmaximized windows; keeping the same number of pixels couldn't work together with grid-aligned resizes), but on the other hand, the window manager pushes back and reverts the terminal emulator's resize attempt. This generates two consecutive back-n-forth resize events towards the client application. See e.g. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=731137.

In the mean time, we've seen multiple such bugreports in terminal emulators where it eventually turned out that `vim` fails to correctly handle resize events that arrive in short succession. This should be brought into `vim` developers' attention and fixed by them.

Comment: Ah yes I have a bigger font in my vim tab